# spring-cloud-dataflow 2.11.2

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have latest SCDF installed in kubernetes and my spring cloud tasks is working fine with springboot 2.x
however When I upgraded to springboot 3.x and ran I kept having error "Invalid TaskExecution ID # not found"
I checked the BOOT3_TASK_EXECUTION and the ID was there.

Anyone has the same issue?

Thanks

It seems like spring-cloud-task is still checking TASK_EXECUTION table even though task table prefix='BOOT3_TASK_'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue I need to pass in task tablePrefix="BOOT3_TASK_" into my custom DefaultTaskConfigurer